# Correct parameters for RateCard API

Tags: azure, azure-billing-api

I am trying to fetch the RateCards for my Azure subscription, however I am unable to figure out the correct (combination of) parameters for my call to the API. I keep getting the following message:

```
{
    "Message": "Invalid query specified. Please specify valid values for OfferDurableId, Currency, Locale and RegionInfo."
}
```

I'm currently supplying the following parameters:
`$filter=OfferDurableId eq ’MS-AZR-0003P’ and Currency eq ’EUR’ and Locale eq ’en-US’ and RegionInfo eq ’NL’`

I'm not certain whether there are any requirements between the `OfferDurableId`, `Currency` and `Locale` parameters, but I think these are fine. The parameter I'm mostly confused about is `RegionInfo`. As per the documentation (whatever little there is), this is the 2-letter ISO code which represents the country in which I purchased my subscription. I am quite certain that this was bought in the Netherlands, hence my attempt with NL, but it doesn't work. I've tried IE, GB, US and some neighbouring countries, but none of them work.

I should mention, the example in the docs (MS-AZR-0003P, USD, en-US and US) doesn't work for my subscription either, I'm guessing due to a mismatch in `RegionInfo`.

What would be a correct combination of values? Where would I find these values? (e.g. where would I find `RegionInfo`?)

Comment: Just a wild guess....I think there's an issue with the quote character in your request. Can you try with following: `$filter=OfferDurableId eq 'MS-AZR-0003P' and Currency eq 'EUR' and Locale eq 'en-US' and RegionInfo eq 'NL'`?

Answer (score 1):

As per @GauravMantri's response, the issue was indeed in the quotes. The "weird backquotes" (which were copied straight from Microsoft's documentation itself) are the issue. When replaced with normal single quotes (and after url-encoding the $filter value), the query works and returns my rate cards.